# How to assemble php file from different php modules?

Tags: php

I'm pretty sure I just don't get the concept, but I'm stuck.
The task:
Assemble a php file from several php modules. Let's say we have a file1.php and a file2.php lying on a server. I now want to assemble those two files to a third php file, lets call it alltwo.php. This file (alltwo.php) will be offered as a download.
I could do that quick an dirty by file_put_content, but as I understand it is no good idea to build php stuff on the fly, because it is too risky. All the example codes work with .txt files for a good reason I presume.

The most simple trick with include wont work, because I don't want the HTML output as a result but a genuine php file with the code from file1 and file2 in it. No changes, just one module after the other.

Tell me I'm stupid, thats okay. 
But maybe you can give me a hand.

Comment: Give us an example of the two files and what the third file should look like.

Comment: Can't you just the set the header of `alltwo.php` to something like this? `header('Content-type: text/plain');` and then `header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="alltwo.php"');`, and then echoing them with file_get_contents?

Comment: Think of a website template with different navigations. The modules for the navigation are stored in two files, nav1.php and nav2.php. The template is named template.php. I am looking for a way to tell php "if condition A is true, put nav1.php inside the template.php, if condition B is true, take nav2.php instead and save this as template-custom.php". The result should be a customizend template.

Answer (score 0):

This seems ugly, but I guess you have your reasons.

If the files start with PHP tags that need removing I would use file:

```
$fileA = file( 'fileA.php' );
unset( $fileA[0] ); # remove opening tag
unset( $fileA[count($fileA) - 1] ); #remove closing tag
$conA = implode( "\n", $fileA );
```

Then do the same with the second file and concatenate.

Otherwise just use `file_get_contents` and concat operator (`.`).

Comment: I'm aware that this sounds ugly to php savvy people. But its for a reason ;-) I'm thinking of a set of php modules that can be assembled to bigger files. Think of CSS, there you can split up different functionalities in modules and put them together via @import or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

Just as @Tibor B. said, if you need to output the file contents as a single downloadable php file, you can use something like this:

```
<?php
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/x-httpd-php');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="alltwo.php"');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
readfile("file1.php");
readfile("file2.php");
exit;
?>
```

If file1 and file2 have opening/closing tags to take care of, like @Kohjah Breese said, you can integrate his answer obtaining something like this:

```
<?php
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/x-httpd-php');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="somma.php"');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');

$fileA = file( 'file1.php' );
unset( $fileA[0] ); # remove opening tag
unset( $fileA[count($fileA) - 1] ); #remove closing tag
$conA = implode( "\n", $fileA );
$fileB = file( 'file2.php' );
unset( $fileB[0] ); # remove opening tag
unset( $fileB[count($fileB) - 1] ); #remove closing tag
$conB = implode( "\n", $fileB );
echo "<?php\n";
echo $conA;
echo $conB;
echo "?>\n";
exit;
?>
```